# Why is this Jinja code adding an empty line when I use it to deserialize json data

Tags: jinja2

Here is the code that I am using in ansible.
I am at beginner level so please forgive me if my question is naive

```
{% for item in results.response %}
{% for value in item.values() %}{{ value }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}               
{{'\n'}}
{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the data format and the output (no match data to format , I just grabbed two random sections of the stdout and the output file

Data

```
    results.response [  
        {
            "address": "10.224.1.61",
            "age": "32",
            "interface": "GigabitEthernet9/7",
            "mac": "cc16.7eec.1100",
            "type": "ARPA"
        },
        {
            "address": "10.70.0.150",
            "age": "-",
            "interface": "GigabitEthernet9/4",
            "mac": "001d.7151.a400",
            "type": "ARPA"
        },
        {
            "address": "10.224.33.51",
            "age": "-",
            "interface": "TenGigabitEthernet2/2",
            "mac": "001d.7151.a400",
            "type": "ARPA"
        },
        {
            "address": "10.224.32.51",
            "age": "-",
            "interface": "TenGigabitEthernet2/3",
            "mac": "001d.7151.a400",
            "type": "ARPA"
        }
    ]
```

Output

```
,device1,FastEthernet6/0/0,-,ARPA,001d.7151.a400,171.255.50.133

,device1,FastEthernet6/0/0,132,ARPA,84b2.61a7.3a20,141.255.50.134

,device1,FastEthernet6/0/1,-,ARPA,001d.7151.a400,131.1.9.233

,device1,FastEthernet6/0/1,32,ARPA,0013.c446.2d91,101.1.9.234

,device1,GigabitEthernet5/1,-,ARPA,001d.7151.a400,110.1.15.174

,device1,GigabitEthernet5/1,140,ARPA,c471.feeb.a080,110.1.52.173

,device1,Vlan112,-,ARPA,001d.7151.a400,120.224.40.114
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c.f. [the Jinja2 docs here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control)

> You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed:

```
{% for item in seq -%}
    {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}
```

Your code has both implied and explicit newlines.

```
{% for value in item.values() %}{{ value }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}               
{{'\n'}}
```

Take that `{{'\n'}}` line out and try it.  You could also organize it visually with manual space management. Watch the dashes by the percent signs -

```
{% for item in results.response -%}
   {%- for value in item.values() -%}
     {# keep none of the spacing aaround this value #}
     {{ value }}{%- if not loop.last %},{% endif -%}
     {# keep none of the spacing at the end the if #}
   {%- endfor %} 
   {# KEEP the spacing at the end of each inner iteration #}
{% endfor %}
```

Will try to test this when I can get to a server. 
Give me a bit.

Comment: Didn't get enpough time to really set up a proper test. Glad this worked for you. :)